# Iptables forward webinterface of E3531

Tags: iptables, http, ip-forwarding

I have a Raspberrypi with an E3531 UMTS Stick connecting to the Internet. Since the Rpi is headless I wanted to make the Webinterface of the Stick available over the IP of the Rpi.

The Stick builds a network of 192.168.8.0/24 where the interface has the 192.168.8.1 and the Rpi always gets the 192.168.8.100. The webinterface is accessed over simple http.
The Rpi can be accessed either over a wiregurad vpn (build up over the stick) where it has the 10.253.3.4/24 or its maintainance eth0 physical lan interface with 192.168.13.24/24. Ideally the webinterfaced should be accessable over both ways.

My first approach was the lan interface were following two rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.8.1:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enx001e101f0000 -j MASQUERADE
```

The first rule to forward the http requests of the eth0 of the Rpi itself to the webinterface and the second one tho masquerade the source address for the interface of the stick (enx001e101f0000)

Unfortunately it does not work. If I access the Rpi in a browser with
`http://192.168.13.24` The request gets changed to `http://192.168.8.1/html/index.html?url=192.168.13.24` and the error `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE` is shown.

What I am missing out here and where does this "url" query parameter comes from?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the configuration of the http server on the stick, which you cannot change (at least not permanently and without modifying firmware).

One option for you is to run a reverse proxy and rewrite the URL that is returned from the stick.

The higher-level question is why do you need three DHCP servers in the first place.  Consider disabling one of them to simplify the setup.

Comment: Thank you. But you generate more questions than you answer. So the http server detects that the requested host in the http header is diffrent to its own address.
I tried setting up squid with the correct ip but with no success I wont get the html page.
There is only the DHCP server from the UMTS stick. The other IPs are fixed.

Comment: The http server is just sending a redirect (e.g. to a login page) and it is putting its own IP address in the location.  Your reverse proxy will need to rewrite this `Location:` header.  To rephrase about the DHCP server, is there a reason why you need three separate subnets for your business?  Why not put the stick on the same subnet?

Comment: Unfortunately the IPs of the stick cant be changed and also the wireguard itself needs a own network. The Lan interface IP i want to have as a last resort to connect to the device.
I just tested by adding the 192.168.8.1 to the wireguard config so I can define a default route into the tunnel and there it works flawlessly.
Do you have a recommendation for a proxy to achive this kind of http-header manipulation?

Comment: HAProxy is one software that you can consider.  You can connect the E3531 in modem mode (USB) rather than WiFi, and can allocate Wireguard some of the subnet, e.g. 192.168.128.0/25.  That may or may not be an option, it really depends on your business need.

Comment: I saw often that people use the E3531 in modem mode but only to use it for sms. Is it possible to use it for mobile internet aswell? Because in the normal router mode it is not possible to change the subnet.

Comment: Yes, there are many guides to modem mode available, e.g. https://support.emnify.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001721233-How-to-use-a-Huawei-E3531-in-Modem-Mode but you can search for others.  The main issue with modem mode is that the Raspberry Pi power supply needs to be good enough to power the modem too, or use a powered USB hub.